# how to get and install in one line , wth curl and dpkg

Tags: bash, curl, dpkg

I want to get and install in bash one line, like:

```
curl XXX.deb | dpkg -i
```

but dpkg report argument missing
how to get it work?

Answer (score 10):

I suggest to add `-o` to `curl` to avoid to redirect to `stdout` the binary file like:

```
curl http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/eigen3/libeigen3-dev_3.3.2-1_all.deb -o libeigen3-dev_3.3.2-1_all.deb && dpkg -i libeigen3-dev_3.3.2-1_all.deb
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't pipe information into dpkg like that. One possibility is combining them with `&&`. Meaning the first command must succeed for the next command to be executed.

```
curl XXX.deb && dpkg -i XXX.deb
```

Assuming you know the filename beforehand and can pass it to both statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wget in a similar way.

```
wget https://example.com/path/someapp.deb -O app.deb && sudo dpkg -i app.deb && rm -f app.deb
```

Plus wget shows progress bar and the local filename is forced (maybe you can't predict from url).